# After migrating to AndroidX, Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, androidx

After using Android Studio to migrate my project to `AndroidX` (and manually fixing a lot of import errors), I'm getting no compile errors but when the app starts I get a crash with:

`Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`.

The offending line in the layout file is: 
`<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`

My dependencies in `build.gradle` are:

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = '2.1.0-alpha02'
    // used below--will be different for androidx (migrated 2019-02-04)
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay2:rxrelay:2.1.0'
    // Relay class
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rx2:replaying-share:2.1.0'
    // ReplayingShare
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.2.0'
    // RxBinding
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"  // see def above
    // includes ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    // for tuples like Triple
    implementation 'com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.5.6'
    // AndroidPlot
}
```

I'm guessing that I'm missing something but I can't find what it is.

Comment: Find `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` and replace it with  `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`
 at app level (including resource layout files.) And then clean build!

Answer (score 78):

You need to use `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`.

Version `1.0.0` is already out So you can use  `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'`

Add dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`

See [Material Component integration](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) for latest release version.
And use

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

For other artifact and Class Mapping see the [AndroidX migration Doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Comment: Well, that error went away, now I get this one: `Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: Replace it with `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: Now I'm getting `Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout` even though I have this in dependencies: `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'`

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` was never part of `v7` its a separate library . Use `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'` .. Read the link above in Ben's answer.

Comment: As you can see above, that is exactly what I have, except for the minor version bump.

Comment: Its `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` not `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout` . Just use Auto complete intellisense to use the right package in xml .

Answer (score 35):

Please go through this old to new [**class mappings**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate#class_mappings)

eg;- Use  **`com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`** instead of **`android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout`**

For **AppBarLayout**

[image]

For **Toolbar**

[image]

Comment: Nice Explanation

Answer (score 9):

Androidx inflating class `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>` will not work
it's not exist so replace it with `<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout/>`
it will work fine
and don't forgot to add

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

to your dependencies

Answer (score 7):

According to [the AndroidX migration docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), the `androidx` replacement for AppBarLayout is `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout`. Try replacing your AppBarLayout tag with this instead.

As for why compiling/building works, I assume it's something to do with Jetifier, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **Kotlin DSL** you have to add this to **build.gradle.kts**

```
 implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0")
 implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0")
```

and in your  layout use  `<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout/>`